# why does int *b[5] forms a difference of 8 bits instead of 4?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, integer, memory-address

I wrote a program to understand a concept of *pointer*, where i declared an **array of 5 integer pointers** and then i tried to print the address of various indices of the array. But what I do not understand is that why is the difference between the consecutive address of indices of 8 bits and not of 4 bits in the output?

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i;
    int *b[5];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        b[i] = (int *) malloc(10 * (sizeof(int)));}
    printf(" b = %u \n\n",b);
    printf(" (b+1) = %u \n\n", (b+1));
    printf(" (b+2) = %u \n\n", (b+2));
    printf(" *(b+2) = %u \n\n", *(b+2));
    printf(" *(b+2)+3) = %u \n\n", *(b+2) + 3);
    *(*(b+2) + 3) = 5;
    printf(" b[2][3] = %u \n\n", b[2][3]);
}
```

**The output is as follows**

```
b = 79107440 

 (b+1) = 79107448 

 (b+2) = 79107456 

 *(b+2) = 3293532864 

 *(b+2)+3) = 3293532876 

 b[2][3] = 3293533008
```

Clearly the difference between (b+1) and b is of 8 bits.**WHY?**

Comment: Which is your processor?

Comment: Intel Core i3-2330M processor 2.20 GHz

Comment: Related: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: For me the code, ignoring all the compiler warnings, shows: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 and 0. Long live 64bit big endian. Use %p to show pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the addresses are in bytes, not bits.  Second as to why the difference is 8  bytes, it is because you are on a system that uses 64 bit (8 byte) addresses.

Answer (score 2):

`int *b[5]` is an array of pointers on int so the difference between `b` and `b + 1` is equal to `sizeof(int*)` witch is 8 bytes on you pc

Comment: Thank You Sir, I appreciate your help of clearing my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you might use %p to show your pointer's address, not %u. In fact, %d is a signed integer, while %u is an unsigned integer and %p a pointer.

Concerning the answer, on your machine, int is apparently 4 bytes but pointers are 8 bytes (typical 64 bit machine).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, unless the last sentence is intended to answer the question. If so, the answer should be reworded so that is clear and is first.